# Advice on learning automotive repair knowledge

Tags: repair

I am an online customer service selling automotive diagnostic tools. Now I have a question, I came to my company since last October. I don't know much about our product, even though I am just a customer service and we have professional technical support. But I want to know more about our product and I believe I can get more customers by learning them. Do you have any idea about how to realize my goal?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  If you're in sales, and the company you work for doesn't jump at the opportunity to educate you as much as possible, there's a problem.  Have you asked for more literature and training?  If you read your products documentation and have a detailed question, we can probably help, but as it sits, this question is a bit open-ended and hard to answer.

Answer (score 4):

First of all , its very smart of you to trying to learn the domain knowledge of your profession you can do the following to improve your automotive knowledge.

- Browse a lot , the real advice would be crank a lot but since you are behind the desk job I am assuming you will have hard time to actually work on a car or vehicle.
- Learn what is required, this might seem contradictory to what you are trying to do but i would suggest leaving the serious stuff to the technicians, you can analyse the frequent tickets or questions you get on your particular product and then learn more on them so that you can sort out the very small issues without going for the techs guys. Remember, the only thing worse that no information is wrong information.
- Since you are part of the automotive diagnostic company you can learn about the various error codes and why they are thrown since that is what the scanner pretty much does.
- you could learn about the ECM and how to connect your scanner to the car.

To be honest learning about the vehicle is a very long and gradual process which cannot be done by reading a book ,secondly I think if your company is not providing your knowledge of what you are selling then there is something wrong right there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah. You are right. Actually I do hope my company can take me in when there are some big activities about automotive maintenance. Thanks a lot!